How can I remove the "Show tabs" button from the upper-left corner?
I don't like the location of the "Show Tabs" button, can I somehow move it to the right or delete it?
I tried tinkering with the flags, but it didn't help. I use the ungoogled chromium browser. I don't want to switch to the brave browser.

